# Incorrect results from OSRM

Tags: osrm

Now i trying to up my own OSRM server (I use vagrant scotchbox with Ubuntu 14.04).

So I follow the steps from wiki and tutorials and build osrm-backend then extract, contract my map.

Finally I run osrm-routed, but for every request it responses with same incorrect result. Points in response doesn't match points in my request and I don't know what was working wrong and what I need to do: re-extract my map or re-build whole osrm.

Also, when I start osrm-routed I get the warnings:

```
[warn] Missing/Broken File: ../../ukraine-latest.osrm.partition
[warn] Missing/Broken File: ../../ukraine-latest.osrm.cells
[warn] Missing/Broken File: ../../ukraine-latest.osrm.mldgr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, and my server works with these warnings. I suggest you follow the new tutorial under https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend, and also add double quotation marks when you make curl requests.

Comment: yeah, u right. i just extract another map (berlin-latest as in example) and it works fine for me, so i suggest problem is in my previous map (ukraine-latest). thank's for your answer